# Refreshing listfragment on database change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

So i have this listfragment which is showing the data from localdatabase. The localdatabase comes from a remote server. So the process pretty much like

1. Get the data from the server and insert to database.
2. get the data from database and set to adapter.
3. show the data.

   ```
   public void onFragmentViewCreated(ListFragment fragment, Activity activity){
      mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
      mDialog.setMessage("Loading Feed");
      mDialog.setCancelable(false);

      mReminderList = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
      final ListFragment mFragment = fragment;
      final Activity mActivity = activity;

      mHelper = new ReminderHelper(this);
      new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Reminder>>(){
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute(){
           // getting data from server
           mHelper.fetchFeed();
           // show dialog
           showDialog();
       }
       @Override
       protected List<Reminder> doInBackground(Void... params){
           // getting data from database
           mReminderList = mHelper.getFeed();
           return mReminderList;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(List<Reminder> reminders){
           mFeedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(mActivity, reminders);
           mFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           mFragment.setListAdapter(mFeedAdapter);
           // hide dialog and show the data
           hideDialog();
       }
      }.execute();
   }
   ```

My code works. But the problem is, the listfragment doesn't show the data before i restart the activity. (and the progress dialog didn't appear). What i want to achieve is the listfragment show the data right after database update (with a progress dialog while it getting data from the server). Thanks in advance..

Comment: try execute AsyncTask at onResume method

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap these two lines

```
    mFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mFragment.setListAdapter(mFeedAdapter);
```

When an adapter is set to a `ListView` the view attaches an `Observer` that listens for changes in the adapter. Calling the `notifydatasetchanged` method notifies all the observers attached. In your case you have no observers attached because you are calling the method before setting the adapter to a `ListView`.

Comment: Every time you are creating a new instance of ```FeedAdapter``` so there is no need to call ```notifyDataSetChanged()``` method. I think there is something wrong with your ```FeedAdapter``` class. May I ask you to post it so I can review it?

Comment: @user1378381, are there any updates about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CursorLoader` for fetching most up-to-date result from local database. Or, attach an `observer` on database to check its update event and update the list accordingly.